# Homotopy equivalence vs deformation retract for analytic spaces

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, real-algebraic-geometry, retraction

I know that there are many examples of spaces $Y\subset X$ such that $X$ and $Y$ are homotopy equivalent but there is no deformation retract of $X$ to $Y$ (e.g., [Does homotopy equivalence to a subspace imply (weak) deformation retract?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3970938/does-homotopy-equivalence-to-a-subspace-imply-weak-deformation-retract?noredirect=1&lq=1)). However, all these examples have some *bad properties* that analytic spaces do not have (or simply are not a good example).

*Given a real analytic space $X$ and a real analytic subspace $Y$, is it true that there is a deformation retract of $X$ into $Y$ if the inclusion of $Y$ in $X$ is a homotopy equivalence?*

In my particular problem I take $X$ a complex variety in $\mathbb{C}^n$ and $Y=X\cap\mathbb{R}^n$; and I have something more: the inclusion is also an isomorphism in all homotopy groups. Maybe some real-algebraic geometry theorem solves this (?)

Comment: There is a simple example in [this MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3794363/2-spaces-homotopy-equivalent-but-no-deformation-retracts-between-them?rq=1)

Comment: @LeeMosher I wanted to say that the inclusion is a homotopy equivalence with the last comment. I edit the question to make it clear. Thanks.

Comment: Then you should also fix your first paragraph; that counterexample does not have "bad properties".

Comment: A trivial example is if $Y$ is not closed. Because (deformation) retracts have to be closed. E.g. $(0,1)$ in $\mathbb{R}$. Every continuous map between them is a homotopy equivalence.

Comment: @freakish that is not analytic, right?